# I am querying SQL data using javascript and want the data to load in proper structure and in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sharepoint-2013

I am querying SQL data using javascript and want the data to load in proper structure and in the same page. The script works fine but loads the data unstructured and in a new page. and when trying to query an image from a url it does not load at all:

I am new to coding appreciate any help coming forward. i am trying to implement this code on a sharepoint site, as i have permissions only at a site collection level and it does not allow anything other than plain HTML and Javascript, i cannot build connections to sql due to restrictions, please find my code below

```js
<script>
 alert ("this is working")
 
 function run() {
 var val=document.getElementById("Kav").value;
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
 document.getElementById('image-placeholder').src = 'https://emloyees.mysite.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/i_0%c7%b5.t_adfs%20prod_'+val+'_MThumb.jpg?&_=q234f42234';
 img = document.createElement('img');
 img.src = src;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
 
 
 //Nothing to try below
 
 function checkAlias1(){
 
 var display=document.getElementById("display")    display.innerHTML=rs2,eof;
 var Alias = document.getElementById("Kav").value;
    var whereid = document.getElementById("srt").value;
 var gaid = document.getElementById("gaid").value
 var objConnection2 = new ActiveXObject("adodb.connection");
     var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=myserver.com;Integrated Security=True";
    objConnection2.Open(strConn);
 
 document.write( "<br/>");
 document.write ("Below is the data from Employee2 table")
 document.write("<br/>");
 document.write( 'demo');
 
//this is from Employee2
 
 var rs2 = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
//sql script
     var strQuery = "select * from mydatabase1..employee2 where ga_id='"+gaid+"' and "+whereid+" ='"+Alias+"'";
    rs2.Open(strQuery, objConnection2);
        rs2.MoveFirst();
    while (!rs2.EOF) {
        document.write(rs2.fields(0) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ");
        document.write(rs2.fields(1) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ");
        document.write(rs2.fields(2) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
        document.write(rs2.fields(3) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(4) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(5) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(6) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(7) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(8) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
 document.write(rs2.fields(9) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     ");
        document.write(rs2.fields(10) + "<br/>");
        rs2.movenext();
 
  }    
        
 alert("code executed")
 }
 
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>


<td>

<tr>

  <select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value="Employee_GUID">Employee GUID</option>
     <option value="Login">Employee Alias</option>
     <option value="Employee_Email_address">Employee Email Address</option>
     <option value="Employee_ID">Employee ID</option>
</select><br><br> Select the search criteria above<br>


</tr>

 </br> 
 </br> 
 <form>
 <input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"></br>
<input id="gaid" type="text" value="">*enter the value</br> 
<input id="Kav" type="text" value="">*enter the value</br> 
<button onclick="checkAlias1()">Check PDI</button>
<div id="display" style="height: 500px; width: 500%;"></div>
<p id="demo"></p>


</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loading data in a new page" ?

Comment: The Query results are loding in a new page instead of same page

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your code is running, but you would need a server-setup to where you establish connection to the database server. Your client (where Javascript is running) should make an AJAX call to the server to ask for response.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Once you have the data on the client, you can use setInnerHTML or similar functions to render the data in form of DOM in the browser.